# Comparing two string tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the following output from an instrument reset command:

```
 reset = power_manager.write("*rst; status:preset; *cls")
 print reset

 Output:
 (27L, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
```

In my code I need to check if the output was correct. When I am doing the check like below, the 'if' statement fails:

```
  if ("(27L, <StatusCode.success: 0>)" == reset):
      print "Agilent power manager is reset\n"
```

I tried various steps like splitting the output and comparing two tuples but nothing helped me so far.

Comment: Well, when I tried to do reset.split(' , ') traceback gave: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: why are you comparing a tuple to a string? if you `print repr(reset)` what do you see? What library are you working with?

Comment: `if "(27L, <StatusCode.success: 0>)" == str(reset))` would probably work but I am pretty sure you can do this using methods from whatever class you are using

Comment: No worries, what module are you using?

Comment: I am trying to control an Agilent power manager to set different voltages and read the power output. I am using pyvisa for this.

Comment: `power_manager` is an instance of which class? Does `power_manager.last_status` return anything?

Comment: ok, power manager instance is created like this: rm = visa.ResourceManager(); power_manager = rm.get_instrument("TCPIP0::130.20.238.190::inst0::INSTR")

Comment: Ok so what does `print(power_manager.last_status)` output?

Comment: I think you should simply be writing without assigning reset then getting the status from the inst

Comment: ok, I will check the output directly instead of parsing the string...will check and get back to you

Answer (score -1):

`StatusCode` seems to be an Object. I would try to do the following check:

```
reset = power_manager.write("*rst; status:preset; *cls")
code, status = reset
if status.success == 0:
    print "Agilent power manager is reset\n"
```

Python objects, when you print them try to represent themselfs as strings, which doesn't mean that you can just compare them like strings.
Whatever module or library you are using, the should be a documentation about the return values of your functions. There you will find more detail on how to deal with that objects.

Comment: Does not seem to be an object: I got this error on trying the code above:     if status.success == 0:
AttributeError: 'StatusCode' object has no attribute 'success'

Comment: That is why I was pointing you to the documentation. You didn't even provided any information about the library/module you are using. And it is an object since it says "'StatusCode' **object** has no attribute 'success'"